# A python script to be running on Django server

Tags: python, django

I am building a Django web application. Part of the functionality involves using the Twitter API to filter tweets and populate my database.

How and where can i write the logic for the program from within Django?
I want this script to be running as long as the server is running.

Would a standalone python script be the solution ? If yes, how do i set it up to run alongside the django server?
Or is there a way where i can integrate it within Django?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean run it once when server starts or keep it running as a background task?

Comment: You need to be more specific than *filter tweets*.   Are tweets of interest being requested on the page the user is on?  In which case Google answer given is relevant.  Or is it like a *keep a constant watch out for tweets on XYZ*   and the page allows you to look at it current hits on XYZ and other watch subjects.  Then that would be more a long-running script, not belonging in a view.

Comment: @ShangWang What I mean is that it is a script that I want running all the time. As long as the server is up and running.

Comment: @JLPeyret Yes, what I'm looking for is a constant watch out for tweets on XYZ and updating the db as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can write any logic using python  in view function: Here is an example i am using google map dstance matrix api

```
def ping_google(request):
    lat = str(request.GET['lat'])
    lon = str(request.GET['lon'])
    point = GoPoint.objects.get(pk=request.GET['point_id'])
    destination = lat,lon
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json"
    geo_args.update({
        'origins' : point,
        'destinations' : destinations,
        'key' : 'dsfalsdfhsdjflajsf;',
        })
    r = requests.get(url, params=geo_args)
    results= r.json()
    context = RequestContext(request,
        {'point':point,
        'results':results
        })
    return render_to_response('gojango/point_detail.html',
                             context_instance=context)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input ! But i doubt i can put my logic in a view because my logic involves automatically retrieving tweets periodically!